# Jquery Close Button issue on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that produce search results on clicking search button. This is the view [image]

and this is html div of it

```
<div class="bestil-menu__btn">
    <a onclick="Searchcontrol(1)" class="btn btn_blue">Ændre datoeeller antal personer</a>
</div>
```

When I press the blue button

```
<div class="dins-searhc-luk" @Html.Raw(view2)>
    <a id="btnclose" class="dinS-bluebuttonC" href="javascript:;">Luk</a>
</div>
```

[image]

it opens the search control and perform searches. I want to close it on pressing Luk anchor in below div to come as it was before. Please help me how to implement it into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$('#btnclose').on('click', function(){
     $(this).parent('div.dins-searhc-luk').hide();
});
```